# Multiple datasets in one graph

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm just wondering if it is possible to create diagrams from multiple datasets in the one graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can use a few different workarounds, such as the `lookup` function or unions in your query to get around this.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258227/ssrs-combine-multiple-datasets-into-one-graph) asked recently.